# Chef noop inside of shell command

Tags: chef

I want to break out of chef if a bash command returns a certain value.

```
execute 'noop' do
  command <<-EOH
    cmd_output=$(echo "test")
    if [ "$cmd_output" == "test" ]; then
       return
    fi
  EOH
end
```

I'm running into an error `return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script`

What is the best way to grab the output of a bash command and then return based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message comes from Bash, not Chef - to avoid the confusion, manually test your script from the shell, before adding it to Chef.

As the error says, Bash will only let you `return` from a function, or another script being included using `source`.  You cannot use it to exit from the main script.

In your example, replacing `return` with `exit 0` should work.